# Bootstrap is not picked up by SpringBoot with Thymleafe

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to use `Thymleafe` and `Bootstrap` in `SpringBoot` application.
However, I could not understand why SpringBoot is not picking up `Bootstrap`.

When I am running my project it's just showing `plain-old HTML` and not picking `Bootstrap`.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Home</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Please Login</h2>
        <form th:action="@{/users/login}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="email"
                    class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter email"
                    name="username"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label> <input type="password"
                    class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password"
                    name="password"></input>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not running in the root context path or if the page is not served at the root path then your script and stylesheet references will not work because they are document-relative.

Consider building the URLs with Theamleaf's URL functionality, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```

Same for the `<script>` elements. Use `th:src` attribute there.

See here for more info:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls